# Navbar on Mysql? or bad idea?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a simple doubt, its bad way creates a navbar menu from mysql?

```
100 users = 100 queries, 1000 users = 1000 queries.
```

What's its the best way?

I never worked with cache, maybe this is the way? Please guide me in the best way.

Comment: If all users have the same navbar, then cache it.... if they all have custom navbars, then you need the database at least once, but could then cache it in session

Comment: Is 1 query per request really that critical to your servers though? How many requests do you get per minute?

Comment: Depending on your setup your database should cache the query on its own.

Comment: @MarkBaker Ohhh, nice idea, use session = 1 query per "day".   I will use both, sessions and mysql "cached"

Comment: @cmorrissey i have dedicated server, VIA Nano U2250 1.6Ghz + 2gb ram + 1gb/s internet connection, but i'm make this website for 'clients' not for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do. Like Mark Barker said in the comments, if you have a custom navigation bar per user, then you obviously will use the database. MySQL is totally built to handle your queries and on most setups, small queries like this get tossed into Qcache (cached).

I personally never feel like HTML should be stored in MySQL, and if that is what you want to do, it just seems sloppy to me. HTML should be in a file.

1000 queries is totally acceptable for MySQL. It is perfect for these small queries.

Comment: *"It is perfect for these small queries."* ....However, it's usually best to properly index a database ;-)

Comment: Well, always @Fred-ii- :D

Comment: I want the owner can change everything without knowing php. And i don't want insert HTML on mysql, something like this: 'id' => 'home', 'title' => 'Home', 'link' => '/home' make query -> make array -> parse array :) I will look for information about Qcache

Comment: @Vincen - Serializing the array would of course be good. It seems your application is more involved and you may be asking about dynamically generated menus. Yes, the database is good for this. Using dynamically generated files is probably bad for this. In that situation, use the database.

Comment: @Jesse Thanks Jesse, You have clarified my doubts.